# referencing parent view controller in swift

Tags: ios, swift

This code is inside child view controller

```
@IBAction func send(_ sender: UIButton) {


    let parentVC = (self.navigationController?.parent)! as! sendController

    parentVC.sendText.text = ""

    self.removeFromParentViewController()
    self.view.removeFromSuperview()

}
```

When the button is pressed, the app crashes with the error "EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION code i386"

Am I referencing the parent view controller the right way?

Comment: What do you mean by "parent"?  Is this view controller inside a container view of the "parent" or do you mean the previous view controller in the navigation stack?  You are getting a crash because of your forced unwrap and downcast; either `self.navigationController?.parent` is `nil` or it isn't a `sendController`.  If you do want the parent, it isn't likely that you want the parent of the navigation controller; the navigation controller wouldn't be in a container view

Comment: in sendController class i have this code :

let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "alertController") as! alertController

 self.addChildViewController(vc)
 self.view.addSubview(vc.view)

@Paulw11

Comment: Ok, so you are actually kind-of adding a view controller's view as a child.  You should read the documentation on `UIViewController` as it lets you know what you need to do when adding a child view controller; in particular you need to call `didMoveToParent()`.   You should be able to say `self.parent` not `self.navigationController.parent` since there is no navigation controller involved

Answer (score 3):

Also, if the View Controller was presented (by this I mean not pushed through a Navigation Controller), you can access the parent with this property in Swift:

```
self.presentingViewController
```

Here is the documentation about the property: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621430-presentingviewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

you can access parent view controller as 'self.parent' in Swift 3.

Comment: i have tried to use self.parent.mylabel but it can't access it or any other outlets

Comment: You can't use `self.parent.mylabel` directly since `self.parent` is of type `UIViewController` - you need to assign `self.parent` to a variable and downcast it as you attempted in your code

Comment: I think it would be better if you declare a protocol inside child view controller and set the parent as it's delegate. Then u can communicate with the parent class using the methods in the protocol.